# Boxploting in R from number of observations for some value

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a need to plot a boxplot in R from some date that come in the form a tabular file (tsv) with the number of times some concrete value appears in a sample. 
I tried to use the following code:

> ```
> freqs <- read.table('tabular_file_with_observations.tsv')
> sample <- rep(freqs$V1,freqs$V2)
> boxplot(sample)
> ```

the `tabular_file_with_observations.tsv` has the following content:

```
0   3040
1   2104
2   1358
3   2153
4   1172
5   741
...
```

what represents is that the value '0' appears 3040 times in the sample, '1' 2104 times, etc.

The R command `rep` 'unfolds' the counts into the sample, but it takes a huge amount of memory and R crashes before trying to draw the boxplot .
I tried to search the net in hope of finding something, and I'm not a pro in R so I'm in need of help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy with `ggplot2`:

```
data <- read.table(text="
0   3040
1   2104
2   1358
3   2153
4   1172
5   741")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=0, y=V1, weight=V2)) + geom_boxplot()
```

The `x=0` assumes that you have only one group; substitute that with the grouping variable if you have more than one group.

Comment: Nice. It works. But how about combining multiple boxplots in a row ?

Comment: Can be done, see the last sentence of my answer or try facet_wrap(). Could you ask a separate question for more detailed answers?